# creating a query from 2 different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a query from sales-order-details and invoice for an income statement sales revenues. 
when I put this into the sql to look up the query

```
SELECT salesno, quantity, price, price* quantity
FROM inventory, sales_order_details
LIMIT 0, 5
```

it keeps giving the same quantity and sales number for all of them. the prices are right and so is the price.. what am I doing wrong?

```
salesno quantity price and quantity*price 
5455     153    2.00       306.00
5455     153    6.00       918.00
5455     153    5.00       765.00
5455     153    4.00       612.00
5455     153    5.00       765.00
```

My sales-order-details table looks like this

SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM `sales_order_details` ORDER BY `sales_order_details`.`quantity` DESC LIMIT 0, 5 ;
```

Rows: 5

```
salesno inno    quantity
5459    6319    290
5458    6318    220
5455    6315    153
5457    6317    110
5456    6316    101
```

and my invoice table looks like this

SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM `inventory` LIMIT 0, 30 ;
```

Rows: 5

```
inno    pname   qoh price   cost
6315    roses   500 2.00    1.00
6316    sunflowers  200 6.00
6317    dandy lions 270 5.00
6318    violets 300 4.00    2.00
6319    tulips  130 5.00    2.50
```

I need inno, pname, price, quantity and the price*quantity

Comment: Did you forget to add the join conditions or do you really want a cross join of the two tables?

Comment: yes, I just need a cross join of the two tables

Comment: OK, what does each individual table look like?

Comment: So then what's the problem?  If you truly want a cross join of the two tables (hint: you don't), you already have it.  Scroll farther down the output and you'll start to see the results for the higher `salesno` and `quantity` numbers.

Comment: SQL query: SELECT * FROM `sales_order_details` ORDER BY `sales_order_details`.`quantity` DESC LIMIT 0, 5 ; 
Rows: 5

salesno inno quantity
5459 6319 290
5458 6318 220
5455 6315 153
5457 6317 110
5456 6316 101

Comment: from inventory 
inno pname qoh price cost
6315 roses 500 2.00 1.00
6316 sunflowers 200 6.00 
6317 dandy lions 270 5.00 
6318 violets 300 4.00 2.00
6319 tulips 130 5.00 2.50

Comment: I agree with @dg99 - the cross-join won't give you any real, useful data (and even when you _do_ want a cross join, it's still best to explicitly declare it, instead of using the implicit syntax).  Like the source-data that's been added to the question, please add what you want your final data to look like.